# Another fix field of a certain galois group action

Tags: arithmetic-geometry, galois-theory, absolute-galois-group

Let $E=\mathbb{F}_p(\!(u)\!)$, the Laurent series field over $\mathbb{F}_p$. Let $K/E$ be a finite normal separable extension. Consider the field $L=K(x \mid x^p-x-a=0 \text{ for some } a \in K)$. Let $\hat{L}$ be the $u$-adic completion of $L$. We write $G_E=\mathrm{Gal}(E^s/E)$ for the absolute Galois group of $E$. By continuity $G_E$ acts on $\hat{L}$. What is $(\hat{L})^{G_E}$?

In particular, is $(\hat{L})^{G_E}= E$? One has $\hat{L} \subseteq \widehat{E^s}$ and [following the answer to one of my last questions](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/248819/fix-field-of-a-certain-galois-group-action) one also has $(\widehat{E^s})^{G_E}=\widehat{E^{\mathrm{perf}}}$. Therefore, we are left with the question if $\hat{L} \cap \widehat{E^{\mathrm{perf}}}=E$?

Edit: and what if we consider for some $m \in \mathbb{Z}$ the field $\hat{L}_m$ where $L_m= K(x \mid x^p-x-a=0 \text{ for some } a \in K \text{ with } \nu(a) \geq m)$? What in the special case where $m=0$?

Comment: You mean $L=K(x \mid x^p-x-a=0)$ for some $a \in K$, right?

Comment: No, such $L$ would be finite over $E$, hence already $u$-adically complete. I would like to adjoin all zeroes of Artin-Schreyer Polynomials to $K$.

Comment: If $K/E$ isn't Galois, then $G_E$ doesn't act on $K$. Why does it act on the completion of $L$?

Comment: Aren't the $L_m$ finite over $K$?

Comment: I don't directly see why. Do you want to explain?

Comment: If $a,b$ have $\nu(a)=\nu(b)=m$ and $\nu(a-b)>m$ they generate the same field over $L_{m-1}$, so we can proceed by induction and the fact that $L_{-1}=K$. E.g. $L_0=K\mathbb{F}_{q^p}$ if $\mathbb{F}_q$ is the constant field of $K$.

Comment: I'm sorry, I am confused right now. Probably it is a problem of notation. By $\nu$ I meant the $u$-adic valuation on $K$. I don't think $L_{-1}=K$.

Comment: Sorry, I got my signs confused. $L_1 = K$ because if $\nu(a)>0$, then $z=-\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} a^{p^n}$ converges and $z^p-z=a$. My earlier argument shows that $L_{m}$ is finite over $L_{m+1}$ and by induction $L_m$ is finite for all $m\le 0$ (and $=K$ for $m>0$).

Comment: Yes, it seems you are right. Another way to see $L_1=L$ would be to say "assume $x^p -x-a=0$, $\nu(a)>0$ and $x \not in K$, chosen such that $\nu(x)=\nu(a)$, then there is an automorphism $g \in G_E$ that maps $x \mapsto x+1$, with $\nu(x+1)=0$, but the $G_E$-action is $\nu$-invariant, contradiction. Thanks a lot for your comment!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The right way to do this would be to give a short, efficient, abstract argument. I, however, will give a fairly messy example to show that $u^{1/p}\in\hat L$.

I’ll use $K=E=\Bbb F_p((u))$, and set $a_n=u^{1-pn}$ for $n>0$, and set $f_n(x)=x^p-x-a_n$, an irreducible and separable polynomial over $E$. Its roots are of valuation $-n+1/p$, and I’ll multiply these all by $u^n$ to form the polynomial $g_n(x)=x^{pn}f(X/u^n)=x^p-u^{(p-1)n}x-u$. This is Eisenstein, so a root $\alpha_n$ of $g_n$ will be a generator of a field $K_n$, which by its construction is one of the fields whose compositum defines $L$.

Now I claim that  $\lim_n\alpha_n=u^{1/p}$. For this, I need $v(\alpha_n-u^{1/p})$, where $v$ is the $u$-adic valuation normalized so that $v(u)=1$, and I’ll exhibit this as $\frac1{p^2}v\bigl(\mathbf N^{K_n(t^{1/p})}_E(\alpha_n-t^{1/p})\bigr)$.

Since $\mathrm{Irr}(\alpha_n,E)=g_n(x)=x^p-u^{(p-1)n}x-u$, this is also $\mathrm{Irr}\bigl(\alpha_n,E(u^{1/p})\bigr)$, and so $\mathrm{Irr}\bigl(\alpha_n-u^{1/p},E(u^{1/p})\bigr)=g(x+u^{1/p})=x^p-u^{(p-1)n}x-u^{(p-1)n+1/p}$. To get the minimal polynomial for $\alpha_n-u^{1/p}$ over $E$, just raise to the $p$-power. We get:
$$\mathrm{Irr}(\alpha_n-u^{1/p},E\,) = x^{p^2}-u^{p(p-1)n}x^p-u^{p(p-1)n+1}\,.
$$
Thus $v(\alpha_n-u^{1/p})=\frac1{p^2}\bigl(p(p-1)n+1\bigr)>n/2$, which establishes the claim.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I indeed like this explicit argument. However, the explicit construction gives me (moral) hope, that in the case of the $L_m$ (especially $L_0$) one might obtain a positive answer.

Comment: Even for $L_0$, I don’t doubt that at all.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not sure of what to make from this comment. Do you believe that $(L_0)^{G_E}=E$ or tend to $(L_0)^{G_E} \neq E$? Double negative and the stress words (even/at all) with unclear reference make it a bit confusing to me.

Comment: Sorry, I am interested in the completed $\hat{L}_m$ of course (too late to edit my previous comment)

Comment: (You can always delete the previous comment and rewrite.) Sorry for the unclarity, but I think your hopes are true for $L_0$: that $\widehat{L_0}\cap E^{\text{perf}}=E$

Comment: That is good. I actually think I have two proofs for this (one showing $(\hat{L}_0)^{G_E}$ directly, the other showing $\hat{L}_0 \cap E^{\mathrm{perf}} =E$). However, I am afraid there might be mistakes (as I really want the statement to be correct, which I think is psychologically dangerous), so I am always happy about seeing an independent opinion. I don't think my proofs work for $m <0$ though. I do not really need this case, however it might make things (in the application of the statements) even 'nicer' for me.

Comment: If your proofs aren’t long, why don’t you send them to me by e-mail, and we can discuss? I’m retired, you know, have a certain amount of time free.